# Liferay not refreshing the whole page when navigating in between pages

Tags: tags, freemarker, liferay-7, liferay-theme, tealium

Liferay not refreshing the whole page when navigating in between pages.

The image request is not firing in prod env but firing in IT env.

The
publishEvent("pageview", reportingData)
Call should be happen in liferay side each time a new page has been loaded

I was expecting that it should fire request each time when navigating in between pages